# SELECT from 2 tables with different conditions

Tags: mysql, select, join, multi-query

I've tried to get this for about 2 hours without success. Here is an example of what I need to do:

**Tables**

`people`:

```
nameA           score
---------------------
someone1        24
someone2        24
someone3        24
someone4        23
someone5        21
someone6        24
someone7        19
someone8        20
someone9        24
someone10       24
```

`runs`:

```
nameB           add
---------------------
someone1        s
someone2
someone2
someone4        s
someone5
someone4
someone7        s
someone8        s
someone7
someone7        s
```

Please note, this is only a example to visually show my problem. No need to talk about the setting of my tables.

**What I want to know:**
First of all I need all entries from table `people` where the score is smaller than 24 (easy till here).

Next step is to only show results where people.name has no `s` in table `runs` (my actual problem).

**Output should be:**

```
name            score
---------------------
someone2        22      /*  no "s"-entry in runs        */
someone5        21      /*  also no entries             */
```

Unfortunately im not very fimiliar with joins.
Here is my last try:

```
SELECT nameA,score FROM runs,people WHERE people.nameA = runs.nameB
AND people.score < 24
AND runs.add != "s"
GROUP BY people.nameA
```

**In pseudo-code:**

```
foreach Person in (SELECT nameA as Person,score FROM people WHERE score < 24)
SHOW name.B = Person WHERE add != "s"
```

I know this is shit :). But it describes what I need in 2 lines.

I would appreciate any help here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from people where score<24 and 
name in (select name from runs where add!=s) and
name not in (select name from runs where add=s)
```

Comment: Is this paying attention that the names in `runs` can be there multiple times?

Comment: Edited...I think you are ok now

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT people.nameA,runs.score FROM runs,people WHERE people.nameA = runs.nameB
AND people.score < 24
AND people.nameA NOT IN (SELECT runs.nameB FROM RUNS WHERE runs.add = "s")
GROUP BY people.nameA
```

Comment: Thanks for tryin. Picked apomene's.